# Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB). Control Add/Not add classes in the help file from source code file

Tags: c#-4.0, sandcastle

In Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB)
Is it possible to control Add/Not add classes in the help file from source code file?

For example, remove classes from help file for classes that doesn't have  comments.

I can use API Filter in Help File Builder.
But keeping track of data in a large class tree in the API Filter dialog is deadly boring.
It would be convenient to mark \ unmark classes (methods, properties) directly in the source files using attributes or special comments.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - the `exclude` element is used to indicate that a particular type or member should be excluded from the documentation.

```
/// <summary>
/// This method will not appear in the help file even though it is public.
/// </summary>
/// <exclude />
public void UndocumentedMethod()
{
}
```

**Please note** - this is a custom XML comments element implemented by the Sandcastle Help File Builder. It will not appear in the list of valid elements for XML comments IntelliSense.

This element has been deprecated in favor of using the project's API Filter project property to exclude members. The help file builder will translate members with this element into an API filter entry. Be aware that if used on an overloaded member, all versions of the overloaded member will be removed from the documentation due to the way the API filter works in Sandcastle.

You should use the [API Filter Property](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/7df16a60-f718-4b8f-bfa2-88c42906070c.htm) to explicitly include/exclude certain classes and namespaces.